# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INSERT"

Tags: plsql

I executing the Below PLSQL Query.

```
SET SERVEROUT ON;
Create or Replace Trigger bi_Shippers
Before INSERT on Shippers
For EACH ROW
ENABLE
DECLARE
v_User VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
SELECT user INTO v_User from Dual;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('You Just inserted a Line'||v_User);
END;

INSERT into shippers(shipperid) VALUES(5);
```

I am Getting the below Error.
Trigger BI_SHIPPERS compiled

LINE/COL  ERROR

---

8/1       PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INSERT" 
Errors: check compiler log

Please help on this as I am new to PLSQL.``

Answer (score 5):

You need to end procedure with Slash (`/'):

```
END;
/
INSERT into shippers(shipperid) VALUES(5);
```

Comment: Thank You for the Solution.But it is not working.I am getting the below error.

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'SYSTEM.BI_SHIPPERS' is invalid and failed re-validation
04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"
*Cause:    A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was
           found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization
           failed for the trigger.
*Action:   Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,
           disable the trigger, or drop the trigger.

Comment: Yes It is oracle DB.The single Insert line is working

Comment: @SatyabrataKar remove `ENABLE` after `For EACH ROW`

Comment: @SatyabrataKar what `user` you expect to get from `dual` table? is this the real trigger? check error using tip from http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_04098_trigger_string_string_is_invalid_and_failed_re_validation.htm

Comment: I am expecting'System' User from dual table.There is no error in trigger side as I am getting "Trigger BI_SHIPPERS compiled" in output.

Comment: Errors for TRIGGER bi_Shippers:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- ---------------------------------------------------------
7/1      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INSERT"